Kubernetes pod fetch to another pod fails
I have a app that I am trying to deploy to Kubernetes (using Docker Desktop).
The app has 2 pods, each with one component:
API pod

A node.js Express app that has a POST API
Listens on port 8000

WEB pod

A node.js Express app that serves up a static web page
Listens on port 8080
The web page has a button that fetches an api on the WEB component
The api on the web app in turn does a fetch to the API component

The idea is I want the WEB pod to be exposed to the outside world, but I do not want to expose any of the other pods to anyone but the other pods in the cluster.  Eventually I will add in a database, worker components, a queue and Redis that should all be hidden in the cluster away from the outside.  Nothing special about the architecture.
The web page is served up fine and the call to the api on the web server works great too.
The call from the WEB pod to the API pod gives me trouble:
The URL I am trying is:   http://localhost:8000
The error I get is:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /app/server.js:51:17 {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.107.140.254:8000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1605:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '10.107.140.254',
    port: 8000

In addition to localhost, I have tried:

0.0.0.0
127.0.0.1
host.docker.internal
k8s-api       (the service name for the API pod, see yaml below)
server-cluster-ip-service (the service name for a cluster I tried)

I found a page that suggested maybe the web node.js was resolving to ipv6 so I added this to the top of my WEB nodejs app without success:
var dns = require('node:dns');
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');

I am able to successfully curl the API (from the MacOS host) with:
curl -d '{"x": 1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000
So I am confident the API is working.
Here's the code that is in the WEB nodejs api that attempts to fetch the API pod:
await fetch('http://localhost:8000', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({}}) })
        .then(r => Promise.all([r, r.status !== 200 ? r.text() : r.json()]))
        .then(([r, json]) => {
                if (r.status !== 200) {
                        console.log(r); console.log(json);
                        }
                })
        .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                }
        );

Here are my manifest yamls:
api.deployment.yml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-api
  labels:
    app: k8s-api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    name: "api"
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: k8s-api
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s-api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-api
        yada: booyah
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: k8s-sample-api
        name: k8s-api
        imagePullPolicy: Never

web.deployment.yml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-web
  labels:
    app: k8s-web
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: "web"
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: k8s-web
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s-web-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-web
        yada: booyah
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: k8s-sample-web
        name: k8s-web
        imagePullPolicy: Never

I also tried putting them together in a Cluster service (with a selector based on the yada: booyah label) using
cluster.deployment.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    yada: booyah
  ports:
    - name: "8000"
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
    - name: "8080"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080

This is what kubectl get all shows:
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/k8s-api-deployment-8cf4dcd8c-p7gbz    1/1     Running   0          2m38s
pod/k8s-web-deployment-7cdf999d48-mx76j   1/1     Running   0          4s

NAME                                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/k8s-api                     LoadBalancer   10.108.64.186   localhost     8000:30825/TCP      2m38s
service/k8s-web                     LoadBalancer   10.106.86.200   localhost     8080:32391/TCP      4s
service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP             36h
service/server-cluster-ip-service   ClusterIP      10.109.42.57    <none>        8000/TCP,8080/TCP   4s

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/k8s-api-deployment   1/1     1            1           2m38s
deployment.apps/k8s-web-deployment   1/1     1            0           4s

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/k8s-api-deployment-8cf4dcd8c    1         1         1       2m38s
replicaset.apps/k8s-web-deployment-7cdf999d48   1         1         1       4s

Any suggestions?

You had Added localhost:8000 from the frontend server, instead, you should define the original values of the service which is http://k8s-api:8000 in your case, also for internal connection use ClusterIP.
Also, check whether the backend service giving 200 response by exposing the Host Port.
Moreover you can create Service DNS which is static forever:
serviceName.namespaceName.svc.cluster.local

Thanks - using k8s-api worked!    I can still access the back end API via curl from my MacOS host terminal though - how do I modify my deployments to make the API unavailable to the host, but still available to the WEB pod?

you can use kubernetes network-policies to restrict inbound and outbound traffic to particular pods/deployments.
You can refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/
